# Generate downloadable QR codes in java script front end

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have unique ids in my NodeJS back-end. After I pass these id's to my Vue.js front-end, I want to generate jpeg/png/pdf/qr codes from my front-end.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to find qr-code generating library for the specific framework you are using. In this case you are searching for `vue.js` so there is [qrcode.vue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode.vue) which would do the work for you.

sample code from the site, which would generate qrcode on front end

HTML :

```
<qrcode-vue :value="value" :size="size" level="H"></qrcode-vue>
```

JS:

```
<script>
import QrcodeVue from 'qrcode.vue';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      value: 'https://example.com',
      size: 300
    }
  },
  components: {
    QrcodeVue
  }
}
</script>
```